# Integrating PayU payments gateway

Tags: payumoney, payu

I am trying to integrate PayU payment gateway on my website, referring [their documentation](https://devguide.payu.in/merchant-integration/payu-hosted-checkout/payu-hosted-checkout-integration/).
They are recommending to use merchant key as a hidden input field but should i really put my merchant key on the frontend as a educated user can easily find it out. I tried making the payment request from my backend and sending the HTML recieved to the user but the script file is not loading is stuck on the loading page. What can i do to load the script file so that it redirects to the payment page.

[image]

Comment: Are you worried that someone will steal your merchant key and send you money against your will?

Comment: maybe..xD, i was just curious if i can do this stuff on my backend but now it seems like theres no problem doing it on the frontend.